# Split on separators not giving exact output

Tags: python, python-3.x, split

```
def split_on_separators(word, separators):

    """
    Return a list of non-empty, non-blank strings from the original string
    determined by splitting the string on any of the separators.
    separators is a string of single-character separators.

    >>> split_on_separators("Wow! Fantastic, you're done.", "!,")
    ['Wow', ' Fantastic', " you're done."]
    """

    word_list = []

    for ch in word.split():
        stripped = ch.strip(separators)
        word_list.append(stripped)

    return word_list 




#output
['Wow', 'Fantastic', "you're", 'done.']
```

The separators are removed but I can't seem to get the white space in front of the F. Secondly 'you're done.' is not in a single string

Any Help would be greatly appreciated :) 
I'm using python 3

Comment: Hint: you're splitting your list with `split()`, which use the space to split by default.

Comment: `re.split` is far better suited to this task.  If you are permitted to use `re`.

Comment: unfortunately I can't use re

Answer (score 2):

One solution could be:

```
def split_on_separators(word, separators):

    word_list = [word]
    auxList = []

    for sep in separators:
        for w in word_list:
            auxList.extend(w.split(sep))
        word_list = auxList
        auxList = list()
    return word_list
```

> Out[76]: ['Wow', ' Fantastic', " you're done."]

Comment: This is almost how I'd do it. However, you're not dropping empty strings. I'd replace the inner loop with a list comprehension: `[w for word in word_list for w in word.split(sep) if w]`. The `if w` at the end ensures you don't include empty strings.

Comment: That is a nice  improvement... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job:

```
def split_on_separators(word, separators):
    for sep in separators:
        word = word.replace(sep, '^#^')
    return [x.strip() for x in word.split('^#^')]
```

The `^#^` is just a placeholder. I made it a weird character combination to make sure it doesn't appear in a normal sentence. You can replace it, if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Another crazy solution:

```
import itertools
def split_on_separators(word, separators):
    groups = itertools.groupby(word, lambda char: char in separators)
    return [''.join(letters) for is_sep, letters in groups if not is_sep]
```

For the case where two separators can be adjacent (and you want to represent it as an empty word):

```
import itertools
def split_on_separators(word, separators):
    groups = itertools.groupby(word, lambda char: char in separators)
    seps2words = lambda letters: [''] * (len(tuple(letters)) - 1)
    return [word for is_sep, letters in groups
            for word in ([''.join(letters)] if not is_sep else seps2words(letters))]
```

Answer (score 0):

You're splitting prior to stripping it.  Splitting is done based on whitespace between words; therefore, you won't see it in your final output.  That is also the reason "you're done" is not a single string.  It splits it based on white space between the words.

You might try a delimiter for the split:

> str.split([sep[, maxsplit]]) Return a list of the words in the string,
>   using sep as the delimiter string.

Comment: but if i do, for ch in word: then the output is every single letter for every word